# object instancer animation nodes only work on a clean new blend file?

Tags: animation-nodes

i don't know if Jacques Lucke is here on blenderstack for help but
it seems that i can't make the object instancer node work on top the work i'm currently doing

in the picture below, i set the instance of the object to 3, i know (from my observation) that without any other nodes involved the object instances will pop right at the center location of the world, in this case where my object is at. but all i select when i try to place the instances around is the object alone, no other instances.

[image]

i tried the same with a new blend file
[image]

no problems

there must be a setting to set here but i just dont know :(

Comment: maybe it has something to do with layers. otherwise please upload the file if possible

Comment: probably sir, is there an issue with layers?

Comment: the test object is on the 8th scene, layer 6 (horizontally)

Comment: the instanced objects are in the same layer as the source, but not in the same scene! each node tree has a scene attached to it (you see which one in the left toolbar). also you can use a "Create Scene List" node to tell the Instancer node which scenes the instances should be in.

Comment: ok, then please upload the file, I don't know how to help otherwise..

Comment: i erased the comment when i saw the incremented number on the scene name,  sorry, it solved it as you said, my instancer referred to a different scene.


So the object instances are defaulted to appear in the first scene instead of the current?

Comment: Thanks for the great addon again sir :)
 I'll put your comment in the answer now

Comment: right. everything else proved to be more complex when working with multiple scenes. you can change it manually though :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40669/discussion-between-pow-and-jacques-lucke).

Answer (score 1):

The instanced objects are in the same layer as the source, but not in the same scene! each node tree has a scene attached to it (you see which one in the left toolbar). also you can use a "Create Scene List" node to tell the Instancer node which scenes the instances should be in.

Answer (score 0):

Reset Instance Object under Instancer Node.

Comment: Suggestions ("Try also ...") should be added as a comment.